# vim using gf option with env variable

Tags: vim

I often use gf in vim to open files. Often these file paths use environment variables. 
I am using tcl shell to launch some scripts.  When the environment variable is used without ::env (option which is necessary for env for tcl), vim has no trouble understanding it. But when it does contain, vim is unable to use the environment variable value.

This works for gf:

*$hello/bla.tcl*

This does NOT work for gf:

*$::env(hello)/bla.tcl*

Answer (score 1):

If there are spaces before and after the file name, you can do with

```
viWgf
```